# Tizkit: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/shape1'

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-external, pgfkeys

I'm trying to use tikzit, and I created a shape (basically a new kind of node). The shape is located into /home/user/.config/tikzit/shapes/shape1 but tikzit (and pdflatex as well, obviously) doesn't seem to find it. I have tried both with debian8 and fedora21, but the problem seems to persist.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer,nodelayer,main}

\tikzstyle{none}=[inner sep=0pt]


\tikzstyle{node1}=[shape1,fill=White,draw=Black]


\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=node1] (0) at (-1.75, 1) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you need to make it into a library or a package and put it in a TEXMF tree somewhere? (But it is a long time since I used tikzit, even if I'm remembering that's what I used.) By the way, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. You should use `\tikzset` instead.